# Get Enum Values from int

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

How can get the enum values from an int input?
Let's say I have this enum below.

```
[Flags]
public enum Weeks
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}

public List<Weeks> GetEnumValues(int input)
{
    // Don't know what is the logic here
    // Help is much appreciated
}
```

Then the output is as follows

```
Examples:
1.) input = 3; This means Sunday and Monday hence 1 + 2 = 3; This should return List<Weeks> { Sunday, Monday }
2.) input = 20; This means Tuesday and Thursday hence 4 + 16 = 20; This should return List<Weeks> { Tuesday, Thursday }
3.) input = 40; This means Wednesday and Friday hence 8 + 32 = 40; This should return List<Weeks> { Wednesday, Friday }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to return just 2 elements of Enum or do you need to receive more items when input is > 40 ?

Comment: Hi Ga ber-ber, Thanks, but I think you miss understood what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could be more. A good example where to apply this kind of situation is applying it in security. A user can have multiple security, not just 2.

Comment: All you need is just to learn how to extract bits from an integer.

Comment: this is not about enum, this is about how to get proper bits given a number'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by looping every enum "flag" and checking for each "flag" if the bit is set in your input value. Here is one way to do this:

```
public List<Weeks> GetEnumValues(int input)
{
    Weeks inputEnum = (Weeks)input;
    var list = new List<Weeks>();

    foreach(var enumFlag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Weeks)).Cast<Weeks>())
    {
        if (inputEnum.HasFlag(enumFlag))
        {
            list.Add(enumFlag);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: this should not be a list of enums

Comment: @Sherlock: I don't understand what you mean. OP is asking for a list of `Weeks` values.

Comment: @Sherlock: How do you know what OP actually needs or wants?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed the answer to my headache. I tried the solution and I get the result I need.

Comment: Based on the example, days are part of the enum, not the enum itself

Comment: @Sherlock "This should return `List<Weeks> { Sunday, Monday }`"

Comment: Intriguing, haha sorry im a little bit curious, let us say I select `Weeks.Monday`, is the return of this still an enum type?

Comment: @Sherlock: yes, `Weeks.Monday` is of type `Weeks`. That's how enums work.

Comment: @sstan oww, I thought this should return an integer, sorry about that. 
The possible solution I think was to receive the input then convert it to binary, then from that binary I will check it's bit position if it's on. The position then corresponds to the correct enum index

Comment: @mercu: I certainly don't want to tell you what to do, but I notice that you've been on SO for some time now and have asked a number of questions, but have never accepted any of the provided answers. Maybe something to consider.

Comment: oh, thanks for that. That would really an eye opener.

Answer (score 1):

@sstan's answer is correct and I voted as answer. But I just want to share also my short version from his solution.

```
public List<Weeks> GetEnumValues(int input)
{
    Weeks inputEnum = (Weeks)input;
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Weeks)).Cast<Weeks>().Where(x => inputEnum.HasFlag(x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - making use of the fact that ToString on a Flags enum builds a comma separated list of the values. Then we can take that and convert each element back to the enum value via Enum.Parse:

```
public List<Weeks> GetEnumValues(int input)
{
    return ((Weeks)input)
         .ToString()
         .Split(',')
         .Select(day => Enum.Parse(typeof(Weeks), day))
         .ToList();
}
```

The choice is yours...